# Broken if statement, can't figure out why this won't work

Tags: python, if-statement, ftp

The code keeps getting stuck even if the directory does exist in the list. I'm not sure what's going on here. When I comment out the code I wrote to re-ask the user for a directory if the directory doesn't exist, the code works perfectly.

```
def path_sel():
path = raw_input("Select desired working directory: ")
b = []
ftp.retrlines('LIST', b.append)
if path not in b:
    print "ERROR- Directory does not exist.\n"
    path_sel()
else:
    print '\nChanging to '+ path, '\n'
    ftp.cwd(path)
    print path
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    c = []
    ftp.retrlines('LIST', c.append)
    if 'd' in str(c[0]):
            path_sel()
file_dl()
```

Comment: you have indentation problem, I guess it is only here but you probably want to fix it.

Comment: Don't start again by calling `path_sel` from within `path_sel`. Use a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me (I picked a random FTP server):

```
from ftplib import FTP 

def path_sel():
   path = raw_input("Select desired working directory: ")
   b = []
   ftp.retrlines('LIST', b.append)

   found = False
   for entry in b:
      if path in entry:
         found = True

   if not found:
      print "ERROR- Directory does not exist.\n"
      path_sel()
   else:
      print '\nChanging to '+ path, '\n'
      ftp.cwd(path)
      print path
      ftp.retrlines('LIST')
      # After printing the directory, you probably
      # want to ask the user to enter a new file/path
      # rather than just assuming that they are interested
      # in the first entry in the ftp.retrlines() printout
      c = []
      ftp.retrlines('LIST', c.append)
      if 'd' in str(c[0]):
         path_sel()
   # ---------------------------------------------------
   # Once you've extracted a filename, run your function
   # ---------------------------------------------------
   print 'Running file_dl()'
   #file_dl(filename)

ftp = FTP('ftp.debian.org')
ftp.login()
path_sel()
```

It continually returns "ERROR- Directory does not exist" and asks for new input until a valid path is entered.  Once you get down to a file (something that does not start with 'drwxrwxrwx ....'), you want to execute your file_dl() function.

Here's what this looks like in my console:

[image]

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's my problem. I don't understand why it gets stuck in that part of the statement.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were having issues with the recursive bit.  My guess is you need to check individual elements in the list returned by ftp.retrlines().

Comment: Yeah I've printed the list to see what was in there, it's just very strange that it will work perfectly for find the "d" in the list to determine there is a directory, and it needs to ask for a directory again or if the "d" isn't there and it runs file_dl. Yet, as soon as I try to add the part to determine if the directory's name is real it gets stuck